# Combining two separate forms into one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been messing around with a two forms and would like to combine them. Each form has a separate JS.

I'd like to be able to take the values in Form #1 and have them placed in the Form#2 answers.

Could somebody please assist?

**Form #1**

```
$(window).load(function(){
jQuery(function($) {

    var multiTags = $("#multi");

    function handler(e) {
        var jqEl = $(e.currentTarget);
        var tag = jqEl.parent();
        switch (jqEl.attr("data-action")) {
        case "add":
            tag.after(tag.clone().find("input").val("").end());
            break;
        case "delete":
            tag.remove();
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function save(e) {
        var tags = multiTags.find("input.tag").map(function() {
            return $(this).val();
        }).get().join(',');
        alert(tags);
        return false;
    }

    multiTags.submit(save).find("a").live("click", handler);
});
});

</script>
```

**Form #2**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.submit').click(function(){
    var answers = [];
    $.each($('.field'), function() {
        answers.push($(this).val()); 
    });

    if(answers.length == 0) { 
        answers = "none"; 
    }   
    alert(answers);
    return false;                           
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Here's the link: http://eurothermwindows.com/ed/inputform.php I'd like to have the Tag textboxes added to the submit that is being processed for the other textboxes

Comment: So you want the form to take into account the dyanmic textboxes?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Somehow migrating the save function into the form#2

Comment: This should get you started. It captures whatever is inputed in the textboxes and assigns it to a variable, which you could then pass on to the script that handles the form, and then parse it so that it's formated correctly. http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/4AfTR/

Comment: Great thanks. I'll play with it.

Comment: Is there a way to group the inputs so that data only uses input boxes 1,2,3 (for example).

Comment: You mean you only want certain `<input>` boxes to be grouped?

Answer (score 0):

I'll make my comment an answer, and elaborate a little bit more.

I made a [simple little fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/4AfTR/2/) that you can use as a jumping off point for this. Basically, it will grab all values of the inputs on the page and assign them to a variable. From there, your script could send that variable to your mailer script which processes everything...

```
var data = "";
$("input").each(function(index, element) {
    data += $(this).val() + ", ";
});
alert(data);​
```

The script looks for all `<input>` tags, and then gets the value from them via `.val()`. In your form, you'd run this on click, `$("input[type=submit]").click(function(){ ... });` where the `...` would be the code above. Obviously, you wouldn't want to alert what the user had typed into the box (they typed it, after all), so you'd then pass that variable on to your mailing script (I'd google on how to do this, as your mailer script is probably written in PHP, so google something like `pass jQuery variable onto PHP`).

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/4AfTR/2/

---

> Is there a way to group the inputs so that data only uses input boxes 1,2,3 (for example).

Yes, this line here...

```
$("input")
```

...finds all `<input>` tags on the page. If you only want `<input>` boxes `1`,`2` and `3` to have their value assigned to a variable, then give them a class and change `"input"` to `".classname"`. Ex.) `$(".tag")` will only assign `<input>` boxes with the class `.tag` to a variable (`<input class="tag />`).

Comment: Ok. i understand. I think i'm just confused because the example i'm using uses " <input type="email" size="50px" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['posted_form_data']['email'] : '' ?>" placeholder="johndoe@example.com" required /> " to pass to the process.php. I'm trying to add my own dynamic field and incorporating the same strategy. I'm playing with it now. Here's the code for process and the input (showing php). http://eurothermwindows.com/ed/inputform.txt
http://eurothermwindows.com/ed/process.txt

Comment: Just give it a class and then use `$(".classname")` so that it only finds those certain boxes. Or you could probably do `input[type=email]`.